# group result array in PHP

Tags: php

im using array for open a file, if value match in array key, then will open file that related with value. when i try, it will open file as much as  data in database.

```
while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
    $d['grade'] = array("2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
    if(in_array("2", $d))
    {
      include "table/grade2_tab.php";
    }
    if(in_array("3", $d))
    {
      include "table/grade3_tab.php";
    }
    if(in_array("4", $d))
    {
      include "table/grade4_tab.php";
    }
    if(in_array("5", $d))
    {
      include "table/grade5_tab.php";
    }
    if(in_array("6", $d))
    {
      include "table/grade6_tab.php";
    }
  }
?>
```

lets say i have 6 data in database, like :

```
=>grade6
=>grade6
=>grade6
=>grade6
=>grade3
=>grade2
```

If data already found in array then just open once file for each key. how to achieve this ? i try using **if** but data for `grade6` open four times.
[image]

i don't know how to get deal with this, i search for groupping data with foreach but i don't know to open a file with foreach. any answer is appreciated.

Comment: You need to [`GROUP BY grade`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: I think you need a `break;` after every if, so if that is true the while loop will stop. To be fair I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i put group by in mysql query ?

Comment: @НиколаТошић alredy did it, but just stop when opening file on grade6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another array to hold the values you've already used, and you can also simplify your code a lot using a loop.

```
$grades = array("2", "3", "4", "5", "6");

//create an empty array to hold grades once they are displayed
$used = [];

while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    //loop through each grade value
    foreach($grades as $grade) {

        //check if `$grade` is in array `$d`
        //AND check if `$used[$grade]` has not been set (if it hasn't been set, it hasn't been displayed)
        if(in_array($grade, $d) && !isset($used[$grade])) {

            //set $used[$grade] so the previous check will fail if this grade is a duplicate
            $used[$grade] = true;

            //include your php file
            include "table/grade{$grade}_tab.php";

        }
    }
}
```

This solution means you no longer have to add an IF block for each grade.

Comment: i did try code above but not showing the included file, maybe i missing something. but now it's workin'. after you edit some code. awesome.

Comment: @DoxTheaugbey Yeah I made an error in the `if` block inside the foreach loop which is fixed now.

Comment: how if i want export the result as a clickable button instead of including file, so the button will show as much as hit value in array ? can i change it to `echo "<a href=['$used']></a>` ?

Comment: @DoxTheaugbey I'm not entirely sure what `['$used']` is meant to be in your comment, but it's surely not what you want. You can definitely replace the `include()` line with a button though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with store useable data on another array and check data uses or not previously

```
$useArray = array();
$d['grade'] = array("2", "3", "4", "5", "6");

while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  if(in_array("2", $d) && !in_array("2",$useArray))
  {
    $useArray[] = 2;
    include "table/grade2_tab.php";
  }
  if(in_array("3", $d) && !in_array("3",$useArray))
  {
    $useArray[] = 3;
    include "table/grade3_tab.php";
  }
  if(in_array("4", $d) && !in_array("4",$useArray))
  {
    $useArray[] = 4;
    include "table/grade4_tab.php";
  }
  if(in_array("5", $d) && !in_array("5",$useArray))
  {
    $useArray[] = 5;
    include "table/grade5_tab.php";
  }
  if(in_array("6", $d) && !in_array("6",$useArray))
  {
    $useArray[] = 6;
    include "table/grade6_tab.php";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: This could easily be put into a loop for simplification

Comment: awesome, there is so much missing code from my code. thankyou very much. but can you explain slowly this part `&& !in_array("2",$useArray))
  {
    $useArray[] = 2;` i would be glad if you don't mind

Comment: @DoxTheaugbey It essentially adds the `grade` value to an array, which allows you to check if that grade has already been displayed using `in_array()`.

Comment: @DoxTheaugbey there we check this value already used or not in our loop by `!in_array('2',$useArray))` and we are going to store the value on another array for checking